# How To Modify The Type of the :new Variable Inside a Create Trigger Before Insert in ORACLE/PLSQL

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, casting, triggers

I defined the column YEAR in my table STORE with datatype int. The data is inside a csv. When inserting i pass the year as a string, because it is either a number or 'N/A'. I tried declaring a trigger to correct this

It should do the following:
If the inserted string is 'N/A' Insert NULL. ELSE insert the value of the string.

```
CREATE TRIGGER checkYear
BEFORE INSERT ON STORE
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    IF :new.YEAR = 'N/A' THEN
        :new.YEAR := NULL;
    ELSE
        :new.YEAR := CAST(:new.Year AS INT);
    END IF;
END;
```

When inserting values i get a trigger error from checkYear (ORA-04098) inside SQL Developer compiling the trigger gives PLS-00382

Answer (score 1):

The data type of the :new.year variable will *always* match the data type of the column in the table. You must filter or parse your strings into integers *before* placing them in the SQL statement.

Answer (score 1):

You just can use a **`REPLACE()`** function in order to get rid of the case whenever upcoming year value equals to `N/A` such as

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER checkYear
  BEFORE INSERT ON store
  FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  :new.year := REPLACE(:new.year,'N/A');
END;
/
```

Otherwise(if it's a year literal which can be convertible to a numeric one such as `'2022'` ) no need an explicit casting to a numeric value which's already found out implicitly by the DB.

***Btw***,

- you can prefer to adding that to your *Insert* statement such as

  ```
  INSERT INTO store(...,year,...) VALUES(...,REPLACE(year,'N/A'),...)
  ```

  rather than creating a trigger.

**or**

- you can cast directly within the *control file* such as

```sql
    ... 
    year  CHAR(4000) "REPLACE(:year,'N/A')" 
    ...
```

if your importing tool is *SQL loader*.